# How to get a Frame Bitmap from a Video File by DsPack Components?

Tags: delphi, screenshot, dspack

Is it possible to get a bitmap from a video file by DsPack components?

In this case I'm using this code; but It can't take a screenshot Image:

```
type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    FilterGraph1: TFilterGraph;
    VideoWindow1: TVideoWindow;
    btnPlay: TButton;
    SampleGrabber1: TSampleGrabber;
    btnTakePicture: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure btnPlayClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnTakePictureClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

...

procedure TForm4.btnPlayClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SampleGrabber1.FilterGraph := FilterGraph1;
  VideoWindow1.FilterGraph := FilterGraph1;
  FilterGraph1.Active := true;
  FilterGraph1.RenderFile('C:\TEMP\1.mp4');
  FilterGraph1.Play;
end;

procedure TForm4.btnTakePictureClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SampleGrabber1.GetBitmap(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
end;
```

Is it possible to Fix This code?

Comment: What DSPack demos show ? do you need to CONNECT those filters into a pipeline? Download GraphEdit (part of DirectX SDK but can be found separately) and play a bit. You should not only add those filters - you should also connect them. And here SampleGrabber filter should be properly positioned in the chain like `FileReader -> MP4 Demuxer -> Video Format Decompressor -> Grabber -> VideoWindows`. However in auto-connection mode it is probable that Grabber would be considered unneeded burden and ignored. Can you check between `RenderFile` and `Play` what is the pipeline built ?

Comment: @Arioch, `RenderFile` builds the filter graph using [`Intelligent Connect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390342(v=vs.85).aspx). I've used only DirectShow headers for doing this, but as it seems, [`FilterGraph setter`](http://code.google.com/p/dspack/source/browse/trunk/src/DSPack/DSPack.pas#3180) does the insertion of a filter to the filter graph (pipeline as you call it) and about the rest should the `RenderFile` take care of (the Intelligent Connect knows where to put the filter in the filter chain). But you might be right that the sample grabber is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a while I found a sample for solving this problem:

we can use "SnapShot.dpr". this is a sample which distributed with DsPack Components.